# How to convert a numeric column (without a calendar date) into datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

I am working with a time series data in pandas df that doesn't have a real calendar date but an index value that indicates an equal time interval in between each value. I'm trying to convert it into a datetime type with daily or weekly frequency. Is there a way to keep the values same while changing the type (like without setting an actual calander date)?

```
Index,Col1,Col2

1,6.5,0.7

2,6.2,0.3

3,0.4,2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` can create dates when given time units relative to some origin. The default is the POSIX origin `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and time in nanoseconds.

```
import pandas as pd

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='D', origin='2010-01-01')
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='W')
```

#### Output:

```
#       Col1  Col2      date1      date2
#Index                                  
#1       6.5   0.7 2010-01-02 1970-01-08
#2       6.2   0.3 2010-01-03 1970-01-15
#3       0.4   2.1 2010-01-04 1970-01-22
```

---

Alternatively, you can add `timedelta`s to the specified start:

```
pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='D')
```

or just keep them as a `timedelta`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='D')
#TimedeltaIndex(['1 days', '2 days', '3 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='Index', freq=None)
```